# Find out if a particular triangle in 3d space is visible from a given point with arbitrarily many other triangles potentially in the way

Tags: algorithm, function, 3d, visibility

I would like to write a function that returns 'True' if a triangle (specified by its vertices and normal) in 3D space, is visible from a given point in 3D space (specified by its x, y and z co'rds) given that other triangles in the space may act as 'blockers' which stop you seeing the specified triangle from the point.

By 'seeing' and 'visible' I mean it is possible to connect **any** point on the triangle to the observation point with a **straight** line that does not intersect any blocking triangles.

[hopefully this shows what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QMfh.png)

I have looked at 'z buffering' and other techniques for solving the 'visibility problem', however since I am not rendering the triangles into pixels for display on a screen through a particular view port I believe these are not relevant.

My two naieve approaches are;

1) project a line from the observation point through each vertex of a potential 'blocking' triangle out to some very large radius (for my application no triangles will be more than 1000 units away from the observation point say so I would choose 1001 units). I would then have an area behind the traingle with the edges described by the lines I projected in which an object cannot be seen. I would do this for all blockers then find the union of all these areas and check if my triangle under test falls within one of the (potentially many) areas created.

or

2) Again shoot lines to all blocking triangle vertices, find the point at which these lines intersect the plane in which the triangle under test is located to get a projected triangle of each blocker in the plane. Amalgamate any overlapping projected triangles into a single polygon. Then check that the triangle under test is not totally inside any of the projected triangles or amalgamated polygons.

Problem with method 1) is that its hard to find if a shape is totally enclosed by a 3D volume and even harder to combine intersecting 3D volumes into one big 3D volume.

Problem with method 2) there are cases in which the projected lines through blocking triangle's vertices will never hit the plane of the triangle of interest. One can't just ignore these cases either, they can still occlude the triangle of interest, they just cast an infinitely long shadow on the plane.

I'm leaning on method 2, but like I say these methods seem a bit naive, if anyone could suggest a more elegant solution it would be of great interest to me! Description or pseudo-code is ideal, eventually I hope to implement this in matlab or c++ but for now lets keep things general!

Answer (score 1):

I'd also go with your 2nd approach, but with some modifications.

First, let say you're projecting your triangles on some plane. Here you have a few planes to choose from, but I'm not sure which one would be better for you:

You can project all triangles to your tested triangle plane. This way you may easily get an info if your occluder triangle is in front or behind a tested one. The downside is that when you're looking at grazing angle on your tested triangle then the numerical errors grows and may break your solution.

The next option, and I'd start from it is to pick one of 6 axis-aligned planes to project to. Imagine them as walls of a sky-box. Depending on the relative position of observer and triangle you may pick the one along axis with biggest distances. Additionally, picking axis-aligned plane may simplify your math a bit.

The next option could be using a plane that is perpendicular to the line between observer and triangle center. This option could minimize errors when you have triangles placed at extreme angles, but you'd need to test it by yourself.

When you have your tested triangle projected you can compute bounding rectangle for it - this is your area od interest and you don't need to know anything outside of it. You may compute 4 planes that go through you observer and rectangle borders, like typical view frustum.

When you're projecting your occluding triangles you've suggested to join them all into one big polygon but this way you may end up with a really complex polys. I'd go opposite way and subtract projected occluder from projected triangle that you're testing. At this approach you don't need to test every triangle combination, because if at any point your projected triangle reduces to empty one - it means it's already occluded, no need to test the rest of occluders.

And here's the most important part:

AFAIK the only triangles that are not possible to project this way are the ones, that have at least one vertex behind the observer (or exactly sideways). So for those you may clip them with your frustum clipping planes. The result of clipping of one triangle may contain few new ones, but all of them will fit in your region of interest defined above.

If you decide to do all of this please keep in mind that your occluders may be behind tested triangle so you need to account for that. The simplest solution is to clip them with tested triangle plane and leave only what's in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I am deciding to use the approximate solution below to do it in a computationally efficient way.

If you only need it to be statistically correct, uniformly sample N number of points on the target triangle and ray-trace it to the given point. You can set a threshold such that if more than p% rays are blocked, declare the triangle invisible. You can set the the number of points on the triangle to be arbitrarily high if you don't care about time.

(Posting this approximate solution since this question is asked on Stackoverflow, not Maths)